# How do I use NavHashLink to smooth scroll through my pages?

Tags: reactjs

I want to have all my pages on one page that i could scroll through and when i press the button on the navbar, it scrolls to that section.

In my App JS I have the following normal setup

```
<Switch>
 <Router>
      <Sidebar />
        <Route path='/Home' component={Home} />
        <Route path='/Education' component={Education} />
        <Route path='/Skills' component={Skills} />
        <Route path='/Experience' component={Experience} />
        <Route path='/Projects' component={Projects} />
      </Switch>
 </Router>
```

I am using  as my navigation, inside sidebar we have

```
import React, { useState } from "react";


import { NavHashLink } from "react-router-hash-link";

const Container = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  .active {
    border-right: 4px solid var(--white);
    border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
    img {
      filter: invert(100%) sepia(0%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(93deg)
        brightness(103%) contrast(103%);
    }
  }
`;


const SlickBar = styled.ul`
  color: var(--white);
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: var(--black);

  
  top: 10rem;
  left: 0;

  width: ${(props) => (props.clicked ? "14rem" : "3.5rem")};
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
`;

const Item = styled(NavHashLink)`
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--white);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  cursor: pointer;

  display: flex;
  padding-left: 1rem;

  &:hover {
    border-right: 4px solid var(--white);
    border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;

    img {
      filter: invert(100%) sepia(0%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(93deg)
        brightness(103%) contrast(103%);
    }
  }

  img {
    width: 1.2rem;
    height: auto;
    filter: invert(92%) sepia(4%) saturate(1033%) hue-rotate(169deg)
      brightness(78%) contrast(85%);
  }
`;

const Text = styled.span`
  width: ${(props) => (props.clicked ? "100%" : "0")};
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: ${(props) => (props.clicked ? "1.5rem" : "0")};
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
`;


const Sidebar = () => {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
  
  

  return (
    <Container>
        
        <SlickBar
         onMouseEnter={() => setClick(true)}
         onMouseLeave={() => setClick(false)} 
        clicked={click}>



          <Item
            onClick={() => setClick(false)}
            exact
            activeClassName="active"
            to="/Home"
          >
            <img src={Home} alt="Home" />
            <Text clicked={click}>DashBoard</Text>
          </Item>




          <Item
            onClick={() => setClick(false)}
            activeClassName="active"
            to="/Education"
          >
            <img src={Education} alt="Education" />
            <Text clicked={click}>Education</Text>
          </Item>




          <Item
            onClick={() => setClick(false)}
            activeClassName="active"
            to="/Skills"
          >
            <img src={Skills} alt="Skills" />
            <Text clicked={click}>Skills</Text>
          </Item>


          <Item
            onClick={() => setClick(false)}
            activeClassName="active"
            to="/Experience"
          >
            <img src={Experience} alt="Experience" />
            <Text clicked={click}>Experience</Text>
          </Item>



          <Item
            onClick={() => setClick(false)}
            activeClassName="active"
            to="/Projects"
          >
            <img src={Projects} alt="Projects" />
            <Text clicked={click}>Projects</Text>
          </Item>



        </SlickBar>


      
    </Container>
  );
};
```

After watching many tutorial ands trying different things nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Have you enabled smooth scrolling in browser for eg:chrome?

Comment: I believe so, it also doesnt work when i run it on safari